# An expression on greed mentioning the greedy people's never-ending desire for money

Tags: expressions

There is an expression in my language which translates to something like this:

> The eyes of the avaricious are like a pitcher which will never get full (they desire everything they see): 
>   a seashell will not host pearls, until it is content and closes up.

So, despite my poor translation, I think the message was conveyed more or less. 
I was wondering, whether you guys have something like this or not,
or can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @owiuertoiwrut, where did you find that "immunerate" is a word? I'm finding only [88 results](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&biw=1440&bih=734&q=%22immunerate%22&oq=%22immunerate%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23614.23614.0.23922.1.1.0.0.0.0.115.115.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.wiGxQke1W0E) on Google, none of which are dictionaries.

Comment: There's a quote from Socrates that goes: "He who is not contented with what he has, would not be contented with what he would like to have" with I think captures that message

Comment: It's a new one on me too.  It sounds like a portmanteau of "remunerate" and "immune", which I think @owiuertoiwrut has invented.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely don't think it was an unclear translation!

In terms of English idioms related to greed, I can think of a few:

> Her greed knew no bounds.
>
> Give an inch and he'll take a mile.

However, I cannot think of any that have to do with animals, if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Don't worry about animals, which is not intended, per "An expression...greedy people."